# How to copy only a specific amount of file?

Tags: linux, copy

I have a directory with almost 100,000 files inside. I want to copy 20,000 of them to another directory. Is it possible to do this with the cp command or is there any other way?

Comment: Which 20,000 do you want to copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for FILE in `find /your/directory ! -type d  | head -n 20000`; do cp $FILE /destination/dir/; done
```